# Convert timezone offset to integer

Tags: bash, date, timezone, numeric-data

I am doing some timezone calculations in `bash`. I'm getting some unexpected values when converting the timezone offset hour output to an integer to do some additional calculations.

Partial script:

```
offset=$(date +%z)
echo "$offset"
hours=$(( offset ))
echo "$hours"
```

Output

```
-0400
-256
```

Desired Output (I accidentally omitted the need to divide by 100 for the final output)

```
-0400
-4
```

I think that the arithmetic is getting evaluated as octal. How can I evaluate the output from `date +%z` as decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed` and `bc`:

```
date +%z | sed -E 's/^([+-])(..)(..)/scale=2;0\1(\2 + \3\/60)/' | bc
```

This will give you `2.00` back in the timezone I'm in (`+0200`).

With strange/unusual timezones:

```
$ echo '+0245' | sed -E 's/^([+-])(..)(..)/scale=2;0\1(\2 + \3\/60)/' | bc
2.75

$ echo '-0245' | sed -E 's/^([+-])(..)(..)/scale=2;0\1(\2 + \3\/60)/' | bc
-2.75
```

The `sed` expression will turn the timezone into a "`bc` script".  For the timezone `+HHMM`, the script will be

```
scale=2;0+(HH + MM/60)
```

For `-HHMM` it will be

```
scale=2;0-(HH + MM/60)
```

The zero is in there because my `bc` does not understand unary `+`.

If you only ever going to deal with full hour timezones, then you may use

```
date +%z | sed -E 's/^([+-])(..)../0\1\2/' | bc
```

which will deal you integers.

Comment: `bc`... that's a new one for me.

Comment: @datUser Just [a standard calculator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/bc.html). Takes expressions on standard input and produces result on standard output.

Answer (score 4):

`offset=$(date +%-z)` would give an output of `-400` in your case.

`-` after the `%` symbol removes zero padding.

[[1] Relevant answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70972/15181)

Comment: -400 hours?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the timezone is a whole number of hours (GNU date):

```
$ date +%-:::z
-4
```

Otherwise (assume -0427):

```
$ date +%-:::z | awk -F: '{x=$1;printf("%s%.2f\n",x>=0?"+":"-",(x>=0?x:-x)+$2/60)}'
-4.45
```

Or, for older, more limited date implementations, us plain:

```
$ date +%z | awk -F '' '{printf("%s%.2f\n",$1,$2$3+($4$5)/60)}'
-4.45
```

This is still not POSIX because a null FS is undefined for POSIX awk.

For POSIX we need to split characters with sed:

```
$ date +%z |\
sed -E 's/(.)(..)(..)/\1 \2 \3/' |\
awk '{ printf("%s%.2f\n",$1,$2+$3/60) }'
```

Comment: Note that `%:::z` is specific to GNU `date` (from gnulib's `fprintftime`), it's not even in the GNU libc's `strftime()` (contrary to `%-z` which is also not standard but supported by GNU `strftime()`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, it is a GNU extension. Are you implying that a GNU date answer is invalid?

Comment: Not at all, it was a "Note" as additional information. I was the one giving you that upvote.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Simpler, older and POSIX compliant solutions added.